# Entity Framework Core (bug?) - Issue when overriding Equals in the entity

Tags: entity-framework-core, equals

I'm using Entity Framework Core 2.1 and I'm facing a weird situation. I have a bunch of rows with the same values for some columns but different ids in the DB. When I retrieve them using EF Core, only the ones that have different values are binded to object (for ex, I have 17 rows in the DB that fulfil the conditions and I'm only getting 7 objects). My entity is overriding the Equals method so I added a breakpoint on that method and verified that EF was calling it.

EF is only retrieving "unique" rows based on the Equals method and that's a problem in my case as I keep an IsActive column that is not part of the Equals method. At the same time, my entity is overriding GetHashCode method but EF is not using it. In my opinion this is a bug.

Is there a way to workaround this problem without adding IsActive to Equals method?

Let me show a simulated version of the code:

```
public class EntityX 
{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public bool IsActive {get;set;}

     public override bool Equals(object obj)
     {
          // return true when the Name properties are the same. it's not considering IsActive property
          ...
     }

     public override int GetHashCode()
     {
          return Id.GetHashCode();
     }
}
```

**If you have 2 rows in the DB with different IDs and different IsActive value but same name, it will only return one row because EF will call the Equals method and say "hey, these 2 rows are the same so let's keep one"**. In my opinion it's a bug because it should also call GetHashCode. As a rule of thumb, every time you override Equals you have to override GetHashCode and this is one of the use cases for that.

This issue was happening to me when I was doing an include, maybe EF only calls Equals when there's an include. The navigation property is a List with generics.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: The way you are describing it sounds like a bug. However I don't see that happening under normal circumstances when materializing the entity query. Are you talking about some collection navigation property? Can you provide a repro?

Comment: I have just added some code and extra comments. I think it's a bug, how should I report it?

Comment: The question was what code is causing EF to call your overridden `Equals` method? Because `context.Set<EntityX>().ToList()` definitely doesn't (at least in my test with current 2.1.1 bits). You can report it here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues, but they will also require repro.

Comment: This issue was happening to me when I was doing an include, maybe EF only calls Equals when there's an include.

Comment: That's what I meant by *some collection navigation property* in my first comment. So I guess you have something like `public ICollection<EntityX> Xs { get; set; }` inside class `EntityY`, and you use something like `context.Set<EntityY>().Include(y => y.Xs)`? You can report it, but meanwhile the solution is to initialize the navigation property explicitly like this  `public ICollection<EntityX> Xs { get; set; } = new HashSet<EntityX>(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ReferenceEqualityComparer.Instance);`

Comment: I'm not using ICollection, I'm using List<X> so I cannot inicialize the collection and indicate how the comparison has to be done. EF should be smart enough to call Equals and GetHashCode if needs to know if the object are equals or not. I would like to be able to deactivate this feature as, in my opinion, it's a waste of CPU time.

Comment: Well, they are calling `ICollection<T>.Contains` method, which depends on how the actual collection class implements it. When the navigation property is `List<T>`, the `Contains` method uses the default equality comparer, which in turn uses your `Equals` method. Report it to their issue tracker if you wish, but I don't think they are going to fix it. IMHO making the default equality based on partial content (neither by reference nor by value(full content)) like your `Equals` override is far from good practices. Good luck anyway.

Comment: I only excluded IsActive from the Equals as I might be able to reactivate a record instead of creating a new one. But I agree with you, it sounds weird and in 99% of the cases it's not a good practice. Anyway, I still think they should be also calling GetHashCode. Thanks for checking everything!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178229/discussion-between-francisco-goldenstein-and-ivan-stoev).